# Why does 'find' print forward slashes?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

I have the following command:

```
find Acc*\bin\Debug\*.pdb > temp.txt
```

Looking in temp.txt, I have:

```
Accounting/bin/Debug/Accounting.pdb
Accounting/bin/Debug/BackendProcess.pdb
```

Note the forward slashes. Why does it output file names like this? And how do I get it to output backslashes, so I can use del on those files?

Answer (score 2):

find looks for a search string in files. Perhaps you are looking for something like `dir *.pdb /S /B > temp.txt` instead?

Answer (score 1):

I think you used some sort of port for find(1) on DOS. if you have find, i think you may also have sed as well.. and then...

`find condition | sed 's///\/g'`

this should do the job.

otherwise, follow what @Johannes Rössel said.

Comment: Ah, right. Should have thought of `sed(1)`. In any case, a port that imposes UNIX filename semantics on foreign OSes is not really worth using, imho.

Comment: It's the standard `cygwin` port, and both semantics are used by Windows in most places.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking to list the files with the wildcards I mentioned. Dir cannot do that. Find works fine if the output is in the console:

```
find Acc*\bin\Debug\*.pdb
```

will output

```
Accounting\bin\Debug\Accounting.pdb
Accounting\bin\Debug\BackendProcess.pd
```

It's just the file redirection that goes wrong.

Comment: When clarifying your question, please use the "edit" link on the question. Don't post an answer to clarify the question.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you use a poor port of the UNIX `find(1)` command and not the (formerly-DOS) `find` utility. Since you apparently have those tools on your machine anyway you can just use `rm(1)` instead of `del` on those files.

Another option is to iterate over the output and replace the virgule by a backslash (assuming a batch file here):

```
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%x in ('find Acc*\bin\Debug\*.pdb') do (
    set fn=%%x
    set fn=!fn:/=\!
    >>temp.txt echo.!fn!
)
```

Comment: Short note on *why* `rm` works: The Windows API usually has no problems with forward slashes instead of backslashes. However, the built-in commands in `cmd` *do* have problems. Since `del` is a shell built-in and `rm` is not, it works with `rm` even with forward slashes.

Comment: You were right, I had some unix tools installed, and rm worked. 
Thank you very much.